# Self Invoking Functions

Tags: javascript, function, self-invoking-function

Importance of using ! in this code

```js
var testValue;
!function test() { testValue = 3; }();
console.log(testValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `!` indicates to the interpreter to parse what follows as an *expression* rather than as what would otherwise be a function declaration. Function *declarations* can't be invoked on the same line, so without the `!`, a `SyntaxError` would be thrown:

```js
var testValue;
function test() { testValue = 3; }();
console.log(testValue);
```

Only function *expressions* can be immediately invoked. Though, to indicate a function expression, it would probably be clearer to use parentheses around the function rather than `!`, and there isn't all that much point to naming the function `test` if the function name isn't used anywhere, eg:

```js
var testValue;
(() => {
  testValue = 3;
})();
console.log(testValue);
```

Comment: Changing the second example from a regular function to an arrow one will create confusion, specially when you state that there will be parenthesis involved, _which ones?_

Answer (score 0):

Functions are not automatically objects. You should define it inside brackets or assign it to a variable. If you use ! for function definition. It means
    !(function(){console.log("hi");})
Now you can insert () to run that function.